# The value didn't show up when I pass the value through fetch and componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I am currently studying fetch and componentDidMount. I tried to get username and comment from this HTTP address http://localhost:3000/data/commentData.json and put them on the feed(kinda Instagram) but the username/comment didn't show up... If you don't mind, could you help me with which part do I miss or something wrong with my code? I really appreciate your help! I will leave a code below!

This is Comment.js what I expect to receive Username and Comment through fetch

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import COMMENT_LIST from './CommentData';
import './Comment.css';

export class Comment extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      commentList: [],
      commentValue: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* {this.props.commentAddList.map((comm, idx) => {
          return <li key={idx}>{comm}</li>; */}
        {/* {COMMENT_LIST.map(comment => {
          return (
            <li className="commentContainer">
              <span className="commentUserName">{comment.userName}</span>
              <span className="commentContent">{comment.content}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })} */}
        {(this.props.commentList || []).map(comment => {
          //props
          return (
            <li className="commentContainer">
              <span className="commentUserName">{comment.userName}</span>
              <span className="commentContent">{comment.content}</span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

This is Feed.js that I tried to add a comment with username and content

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';
import {
  FaRegHeart,
  FaRegComment,
  FaRegPaperPlane,
  FaRegBookmark,
  FaEllipsisH,
} from 'react-icons/fa';
import Comment from '../../../compoonents/Comment/Comment';
import selfiImg from '../../../assets/images/about.png';
import ucscPic from '../../../assets/images/ucscPic.png';

class Feed extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      commentList: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/commentData.json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          commentList: data,
        });
      });
  }
  getValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  addComment = () => {
    this.setState({
      commentList: this.state.commentList.concat([this.state.value]),
      value: '',
    });
  };

  addCommEnter = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.addComment();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="feeds">
        <div className="article">
          <div className="identi">
            <img className="selfi-identi" alt="selfi-img" src={selfiImg} />
            <span className="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>

            {/* <i id="test" class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i> */}
            <div className="faEllipsisH">
              {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisH} /> */}
              <FaEllipsisH />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="pic">
            <img id="feed-pic" src={ucscPic} />
          </div>

          <div className="show-box">
            <div className="reaction-icons">
              <FaRegHeart className="heart" />
              <FaRegComment className="comment" />
              <FaRegPaperPlane className="plane" />
              <FaRegBookmark className="bookMark" />

              {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="heart" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="comment" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} className="plane" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark} className="bookMark" /> */}
            </div>

            <div className="like-counts">
              <span>like 4,000</span>
            </div>

            <div className="check-comments">
              <span>
                UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or
                online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person
                instruction for a small
              </span>
              <a id="space" href="">
                expanding
              </a>
              <br />
              <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
              <ul className="feed-comments">
                <Comment commentAddList={this.state.commentList} />
                {/* <li>hello</li> */}
                {/* {this.state.commentList.map((comm, idx) => {
                  return <li key={idx}>{comm}</li>;
                })} */}
                
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="comment">
            <i className="fa fa-smile-o" />
            <input
              // onChange={this.textChange}
              // onKeyPress={this.enterClick}
              onKeyPress={this.addCommEnter}
              onChange={this.getValue}
              className="user-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Add Comment..."
              value={this.state.value}
            />
            <button onClick={this.addComment} className="post">
              Post
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Feed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `Comment.js` file this line is giving you the error: `this.props.commentList`, because you didn't define such a prop (maybe you misspelled `this.props.commentAddList`..

Comment: Thank you so much.... I missed the important part. pretty basic concept. I really appreciate your help! :)